# Проблема с делегатом и вызовом события в C#

Tags: c#, ооп, события

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста, если поймете суть вопроса)
Есть условие для задачи, часть из которого "установить статус определенного города с помощью вызова ивента, в зависимости от количества его населения, с помощью таймера из *System.Timers*".
Я создала событие, подписала на него каждый город, и установила таймер на 5 секунд, который меняет количество населения в городе. В классе Country есть массив Localities, однако при конвертации города в село (или наоборот) не происходит сохранение в массиве Localities (если >15000 не меняет статус на City, и т.п.)

```
private EventHandler<CountryEventArgs> _event;

        internal event EventHandler<CountryEventArgs> PopulationGrowth
        {
            add
            {
                _event += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                _event -= value;
            }
        }

        private void TimerHandler(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        { 
            int buff = Population;
            Random random = new Random();
            this.Population += random.Next(-1000, 1000);
            if (_event != null)
            {
                if (buff < 15000 && Population > 15000)
                {
                    _event.Invoke(this, new CountryEventArgs() { IsToCity = true, IsToVillage = false });
                }
                if (buff > 15000 && Population < 15000)
                {
                    _event.Invoke(this, new CountryEventArgs() { IsToCity = false, IsToVillage = true });
                }
                else
                {
                    _event.Invoke(this, new CountryEventArgs() { IsToCity = false, IsToVillage = false });
                }
            }
        }
        public Village ToVillage()
        {
            Village village = new Village(Population, LocalityName, "Village");
            return village;
        }
        public City ToCity()
        {
            City city = new City(Population, LocalityName, "City");
            return city;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Class constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param lacalityName = "locality name">Name of Locality</param>
        protected Locality(string localityName)
        {
            _timer = new Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 5000;
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerHandler;
            _timer.Start();
            _localityName = localityName;
        }
```

```
private void CountryHandler(object? sender, CountryEventArgs args)
        {
            Locality locality = sender as Locality;
            /*if (_printCount < _localityIndex + 1)
            {
                _printCount = 0;
                Console.Clear();
            }
            _printCount++;*/
            if (args.IsToCity)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < _localityIndex; i++)
                {
                    if (locality.Equals(Localities[i]))
                    {
                        locality = locality.ToCity();
                        Localities[i] = locality;
                        Console.WriteLine(locality.ToString());
                        //Console.WriteLine(locality.GetInfrastructure());
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }
            if(args.IsToVillage)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _localityIndex; i++)
                {
                    if (locality.Equals(Localities[i]))
                    {
                        locality = locality.ToVillage();
                        Localities[i] = locality;
                        Console.WriteLine(locality.ToString());
                        //Console.WriteLine(locality.GetInfrastructure());
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < _localityIndex; i++)
                {
                    if (locality.Equals(Localities[i]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(locality.ToString());
                        //Console.WriteLine(locality.GetInfrastructure());
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Класса Country не хватает... Проблема, которую я предполагаю: Вы - как я вижу в коде - в методах ToCity и ToVillage создаёте НОВЫЕ экземпляры объектов. А что с ними потом происходит - то есть, где именно меняется массив Localities в классе Country - я не вижу. Возможно, я плохо смотрел...

Comment: @S.H. Насчет того, где именно меняется массив, это строчка: Localities[i] = locality;
Просто второй код взят из класса Country, а у меня нет возможности его прикрепить, очень длинный класс)

Comment: В `TimerHandler` у вас `if`, `if`, `else`. То есть может выполниться первое условие, а потом ещё и ветка else.

Comment: `_event` - плохое название. Вероятно, событие должно называться `PopulationChanged`. Ведь это же событие изменения населения?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо, дельное замечание) Я нашла проблему, у меня была подписка на прошлый неизмененный объект, при преобразовании Village в City подписка оставалась на Village, нужно было от него отписаться, и подписаться заново на City. Всем спасибо большое за советы)

Comment: Имхо, не очень хороший подход, когда сами сработавшие события меняют подписку на события. Просто чем отличается Village от City внутри? Не достаточно ли флага bool или enum, который будет это определять? Это реальная задача (к примеру из какой-нибудь онлайн игры или симуляции) или учебная задача, чтобы прокатиться как можно более сложным примером?